# High resolution drawing app for iPad

Tags: ipad, resolution, display

I'm looking for a good app that I and kids at my home can use to draw pictures on the iPad. I've used many of the free apps, like Chalk Pad and so on, but I notice that each of these comes with a lag.

What's a good app which helps you draw great looking pictures and has a minimum amount of time lag? I'd prefer free apps, though mentioning paid apps won't hurt.

Answer (score 2):

My girlfriend uses [iDraw](http://www.indeeo.com/idraw/) for vector picture drawing. It’s not free, but it’s the best iPad drawing app I’ve seen. It also has an OS X version.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I like [Procreate](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/procreate/id425073498?mt=8).  It isn't free, but it's inexpensive and is an excellent drawing package with minimal to no lag, and it does support the new iPad's HD canvas.

[image]